# NSLayoutConstraint description is randomly different

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-autolayout

Printing the constraints of a view, they show up like:

```
<__NSArrayI 0x14020baa0>(
<NSContentSizeLayoutConstraint:0x14026bda0 H:[PinView:0x1401f4e80(93)] Hug:250 CompressionResistance:750>,
<NSContentSizeLayoutConstraint:0x14026d1f0 V:[PinView:0x1401f4e80(269)] Hug:250 CompressionResistance:750>,
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x140266560 V:|-(0)-[UIView:0x1401fad10]   (Names: '|':PinView:0x1401f4e80 )>,
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x140232770 H:|-(0)-[UIView:0x1401fad10]   (Names: '|':PinView:0x1401f4e80 )>,
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x140232800 UIView:0x1401fad10.bottom == PinView:0x1401f4e80.bottom>,
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x14024a6d0 UIView:0x1401fad10.trailing == PinView:0x1401f4e80.trailing>
)
```

Why are the first 4 showing the visual format, and only the last 2 are showing the regular (clearer) format?

Is the `description` method returning different things based on the way it was created?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see [in the 2012 WWDC session 228](http://asciiwwdc.com/2012/sessions/228):

> Now for constraints that can be expressed with a visual format syntax it will show that syntax in the log messages.

So it is in fact "random", in the way that the system chooses the appropriate syntax depending on the constraint itself.
It also doesn't depend on the way it was created.

I think it's possible to add a category to `NSLayoutConstraint` in which you override the `description` method and return the same syntax for all the constraints.